# TypeError: data.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, es6-promise

I'm trying to write some code that takes an API response, uses that data to plug into a new API call, and takes the response and does some logic to return it in the right order to display to the user.

```
  makeRequest = async () => {
    let realPhotoData = [];
    let actualPhotoData = [];
    let actualCityData = [];

    const place = this.state.inputValue;
    const url = url;

    // first fetch call returning 8 venues for location searched (picture data not included in response)
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        let allCities = data.response.groups[0].items;

        for (let key of allCities) {
          let searchData = {
            title: key.venue.name,
            city: key.venue.location.city,

            country: key.venue.location.country,
            photoId: key.venue.id
          };

          let venueIdArray = {
            photoId: key.venue.id
          };
          actualCityData.push(searchData);
          actualPhotoData.push(venueIdArray);
        } /* end of for loop, placed response data in 2 arrays, need venueIdArray for 2nd fetch call (loop of 8 fetch calls) */

        // for loop for second fetch call(8 of them) it returns photos for 8 venues

        for (let i = 0; i < actualPhotoData.length; i++) {
          var venueId = actualPhotoData[i].photoId;
          let photoUrl = photoUrl;


          let callPhotoSearch = async (actualCityData) => {
            if (actualCityData) {
              const photoRequest = fetch(photoUrl)
              .catch(err => {
                return { error: err };
                })

              await Promise.all([photoRequest]).then(data => {
                  const photoData = data.json();
                // })
                // .then(data => {
                  realPhotoData.push({
                    returnPhotoId: photoData.meta.requestId,
                    returnVenueId: i,
                    prefix: photoData.response.photos.items[0].prefix,
                    size: "300x500",
                    suffix: photoData.response.photos.items[0].suffix
                  });
                  console.log(realPhotoData)

                  realPhotoData.sort(
                    (a, b) => a.returnVenueId - b.returnVenueId
                  );

                  var photoAndSearchData = [];

                  for (let j = 0; j < actualCityData.length; j++) {
                    // console.log(realPhotoData, actualCityData);
                    photoAndSearchData.push({
                      key1: actualCityData[j],
                      key2: realPhotoData[j]
                    });
                    console.log(photoAndSearchData);

                    this.setState({
                      cardArray: photoAndSearchData
                    });
                  }
                  console.log(this.state);
                });
            }
          };
         callPhotoSearch(actualCityData);
        }
      });
  };
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.json is not a function` and am not sure how to resolve that when I need the data in JSON format.

Comment: What is the data coming back from that call? A dump of the exact same call from postman or something and paste the response, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

usually in the api response, json will be stringyified. Try to use

JSON.parse(data)

If you post your response object, it will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The response object is an array of venues:

```
(4) […]
​
0: Object { title: "Rotunda of the U.S. Capitol", city: "Washington", country: "United States", … }
​
1: Object { title: "Washington Monument", city: "Washington", country: "United States", … }
​
2: Object { title: "Meridian Hill Park", city: "Washington", country: "United States", … }
​
3: Object { title: "Library Of Congress Main Reading Room", city: "Washington", country: "United States", … }
​
length: 4
```